# Существует ли возможность автоматически копировать нужные DLL в папку с программой

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, qt-faq

Есть Qt версии 5.5. Там динамически линкуются все библиотеки (*.dll).
Вопрос: существует ли возможность автоматически брать и копировать нужные *.dll-файлы в папку с программой?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да можно. Для этого в составе Qt есть утилита [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) (ближе к концу мотайте, и к стати статья очень подробно основные вопросы про деплой разжевывает). У windeployqt были небольшие проблемы с QML, но я QML не использую поэтому ничего сказать не могу.

К слову, для развертывания на OS X есть аналогичная утилита - [macdeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html) (тоже до конца проматать нужно).

Comment: Но есть вопрос: как запустить эту утилиту сразу после этапа сборки проекта? Вернее сказать: как последний этап сборки. Ну чтоб среда сама его запустила

Comment: Обычно в IDE для этого существует опция типа PostBuildStep в которой можно написать консольную команду для выполнения ее сразу после сборки. Поищите как это делается в вашей IDE.

Comment: Нашёл. Всё отработало как часы.

Comment: спасибо не знал